# memoir: changing the default font size after loading the package

Tags: memoir, fontsize

Let's assume I load memoir with default font size 11pt.  I want to (conditionally) change the default set of font sizes (main text, headings, etc) **after loading** the `memoir` package (*can't do it before*), but still **before** the `\begin{docment}`.

How to define the `\setmemoirfontsize`command below?

See below a MWE without the "W"! :)

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\newif\ifmycondition
\myconditiontrue
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\setmemoirfontsize}[1]{%
  % do something here to change the all the font sizes
  % \input{mem12.clo} % does not work
}

\ifmycondition\setmemoirfontsize{12pt}\fi

\begin{document}
\section{This header should be proportional to the 12pt size}
This should be in font size 12pt.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you compile with `lualatex` and `\usepackage{fontspec}` then it is possible to renew the `\normalsize` command whenever you wish, because the scalable fonts may have any size (even decimal pt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hack only, because I don't know any official way to do it:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\newif\ifmycondition
\myconditiontrue
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\setmemoirfontsize}[1]{%
  \makeatletter
  \input{mem#1.clo}%
  \makeatother
}

\ifmycondition\setmemoirfontsize{12}\fi

\begin{document}
\section{This header should be proportional to the 12pt size}
This should be in font size 12pt.
\end{document}
```

BTW: There are other classes like the [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes, that officially do support something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\newif\ifmycondition
\myconditiontrue
\thispagestyle{empty}

\ifmycondition\KOMAoptions{fontsize=12pt}\fi

\begin{document}
\section{This header should be proportional to the 12pt size}
This should be in font size 12pt.
\end{document}
```

but it is always recommended, to setup the main font size already when loading the class.